# zsh history is not syncing immediately

Tags: zsh

I have `zsh 5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0.0)` and using iterm2 if it makes a difference with the following zshrc:

```
HISTFILE=~/.zhistory
HISTSIZE=10000
SAVEHIST=10000
setopt appendhistory
```

The file ~/.zhistory isn't populating if I enter any commands.
The file is appended only if when I exit from zsh:

```
echo r3d3
cat ~/.zhistory |grep r3d3 # shows nothing
zsh
echo r2d2
exit
cat ~/.zhistory |grep r2d2 # only this way it will print r2d2
```

This makes it impossible to use commands like hstr. And if a terminal crash I lose my history

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `setopt appendhistory` in your .zshrc with `setopt incappendhistory`.

From `man zshoptions`:

**INC_APPEND_HISTORY**

This option works like APPEND_HISTORY except that new history lines are added to the $HISTFILE incrementally (as soon as they are entered), rather than waiting until the shell exits. The file will still be periodically re−written to trim it when the number of lines grows 20% beyond the value specified by $SAVEHIST (see also the HIST_SAVE_BY_COPY option).